# WPF Views not displaying certain controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro and Telerik's controls.  I'm new to these so I'm assuming I am making a stupid mistake.

I have the below, VERY simple View.  It's just a User Control with a GridView in it.  How ever it doesn't show the GridView.  Additionally I have a View that is a User Control that just shows a DataForm that also doesn't show.

I get the User control but it's blank.  If I throw other controls on there they show, like a RadWatermarkTextBox or a simple TextBlock.

What am I missing?  I don't get any exceptions or warnings.

```
<UserControl x:Name="ModifyAuthUserControl" x:Class="Green.Views.ModifyAuthView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org" 
         MinWidth="500" Width="600" MinHeight="550" Height="600">
<Grid Background="White">
    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="ExistingAuths"/> <!--This doesn't show-->           
    <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Text="HELLO!" /> <!--This DOES-->
</Grid>
```

Comment: What happens when you explicitly bind the RadGridView to your viewmodel?

Comment: Sorry, not 100% sure how I'd do that.  I am getting the impression, as I look into this on my side, that it has to do with Telerik and the fact that I was using there Implicit theming...

Comment: I use the Telerik controls with Caliburn.Micro without much (if any) problem. You can explicitly bind the items source by `ItemsSource="{Binding ExistingAuths}"` and it should *just work*...

Comment: Yeah, I figured out my issue.  I am using the Implicit Themes but didn't have all my Dictionary's Merged.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor Have you run into any other issues of note?

Comment: @RefractedPaladin Not really, unless you want to use `RadWindow` as a popup. Long story short, it's not playing nice with default `WindowManager` and you'd have to re-write some parts of it (the `WindowManager) to make it work. There was an example somewhere on the Telerik forums... Save for that, everything works just fine.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor are you not adding conventions for your Telerik controls? Much nicer than explicitly binding everything

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor Okay, I am using the NuGet package "Caliburn.Micro.Telerik" that takes care of that.  See here if curious --> [link](https://github.com/vcaraulean/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik)

Comment: @Charleh Can you add conventions for C.M. to bind Telerik's GridView and DataForm's ItemSource?

Comment: Yes - just use `ConventionManager.AddElementConvention` in your CM setup (usually in bootstrapper or whereever is early enough to happen before any bindings happen). I usually use `ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<RadGridView>(RadGridView.ItemsSourceProperty, "SelectedItem", "SelectionChanged");` for the grid. The signature is `(BindableDepProp, DefaultActionParameter, DefaultActionableEvent)`

Comment: @Charleh Actually, did not realize this till you posted your comment but the NuGet package I linked in my comment does this for you as well as numerous others.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had not included ALL necessary references in my App.xaml.  Those two controls have multiple dependencies and I only had some of them included.  Once I included the bottom two Dictionary entrees everything worked great.

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your RadGridView and your RadWatermarkTextBox do not have associated grid rows or columns, and will appear one on top of the other.